# Third Order Stochastic Dominance

Tags: distributions

Is there an intuitive explanation (and picture) for two distributions with the same mean and variance but different skewness? I am looking for an illustration of third order stochastic dominance (TOSD) - would a right skewed and left skewed distribution with equally long tails (in opposite directions) be a valid example? The definition of TOSD implies mean and variance of two distributions are the same but one has great downside-risk (implying it is dominated)

[image]

Comment: Could you write out a definition of third order stochastic dominance for the uninitiated?